# Pointer to inline asm label for PIC 16F and Hitech C

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, pic

I am programming 16F886 and here is a sample of inline asm:

```
#asm
psect TxtData,class=CODE,delta=2
global _text1,_text2
_text1:   dw    'T','E','X','T','1',0
_text2:   dw    'T','E','X','T','2',0
#endasm
```

I need to point EEADR and EEADRH to each of the labels to read the flash memory.
In pure asm, I would just use the Low/High operands to get the address of each label e.g. `movlw low Text1`.
In C, I need something like a "const pointer" for each of the labels but I can't make it to work.
I am using the Hitech C compiler for PIC 10/12/16.

Comment: My first guess would be `extern const char *text1;`. What have you tried? And what error messages are you getting?

Comment: What @user3386109 said is the correct way to do this. Also, you may want to use the `db` directive, not the `dw` directive. The former will treat each character as a byte (as you want), the latter will treat them as 16-bit words, which is incorrect for C. You can also use plain strings in single quotes after a `db` directive, e.g. `_text1: db 'TEXT1'`

Comment: when I write `EEADR=&text1` i get "67.14 illegal conversion of pointer to integer". The code produced seems to pass the low byte correct though.

Comment: I need to get both the high and the low byte.

Comment: I think that you need to post the relevant portions of the C code, see we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to convert my old asm code to C. My thinking was to have a long constant and do something like `EEADR= &Text1` and `EEADRH= (&Text1)>>8`. My actual code is in asm and I am trying to change it piece by piece.

Comment: the asm code is: `movlw low text1, movwf EEADR, movlw high text1,movlw EEADRH`. just as simple.

Comment: Have you tried `EEADR= Text1` ?

Comment: Just did.  Works fine! so, `extern const char text1` (no pointer here) and `EEADR=Text1`, pass correctly the low byte and I get no error messages. How can I get the upper bits for EEADRH?

Comment: tried it. Returns the same as `EEADR= Text1`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your kind support.
I posted the question in Microchip forum and several guys tried it out.It turned out that there is somekind of bug in the compiler for 10/12/16 mcus. In C18 compiler or Hitech C18, when set for an 18F mcu, the above proposed solutions worrked flawlessly.
The only workaround that I've managed to find, is to use inline assembly to get the high byte of an asm address label and set the proper registers this way.

```
asm 
    EEADRH EQU  0x10F
    movlw high _text1
    banksel EEADRH
    movwf EEADRH
endasm
```

Answer (score 0):

A string label *is* a pointer - you don't have to specify its address with `&`. You have to write the MS part of the address first

```
unsigned short address = text;
EEADRH = (address >> 8) & 0xF;
EEADR = address & 0xFF;
```

Comment: It does not work. The previous `extern const long text1` makes text1 to behave differently.

Comment: @tcop saying "it does not work" is not very helpful.

Comment: sorry. It returns exactly the same value as before. It seems that the compiler has not saved a 16bit address label but 8 bit. For pic 16F, the address is actually 14bit.

Comment: I can't find a solution. I will ask Microchip about it. Thanks.